# Formatting received data as a table

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am trying to format the data I receive from my database using Ajax via my PHP script, as a `table`. I get a reply but the `table` tags are shown in my `div#name-data`, instead of the actual table. How can I resolve this issue?

**AJAX**

```
$('input#name-submit').on('click',function(){
    var name = $('input#name').val();
    if($.trim(name)!=''){
        $.post('ajax/name.php',{name:name},function(data){
            $('div#name-data').text(data);
        });
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM employee WHERE first_name='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['name']))."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $row['emp_id'].$row['last_name'];
```

Comment: i didnt got ur point sir

Comment: Can you be clearer, we don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: i need to display 11 and john in table format not in text as ajax function is in text!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning tags in your result. You have used the `text` method to display the result and not the `html` method. You should change the line

```
$('div#name-data').text(data);
```

to

```
$('div#name-data').html(data);
```

See here for the difference between [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method and the [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method.

Comment: Thnx alot Scott ... its very Helpfull thanku so much again im totally beginner!!